Django and react webrtc remote isn't being added
I am making a chat app with django for backend and react for frontend. I use django channels.
consumers.py
   def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)

        if 'message' in text_data_json:
            # Handle chat message
            message = text_data_json["message"]
            user = text_data_json["user"]

            print(message)

            # Send message to room group
            async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
                self.room_group_name,
                {"type": "chat.message", "message": message, 'user': user}
            )

        elif 'webrtc' in text_data_json:
            # Handle WebRTC signaling
            signal_data = text_data_json['webrtc']
            user = text_data_json['user']

            # Relay WebRTC signaling data to the group
            async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
                self.room_group_name,
                {
                    "type": "webrtc.signal",
                    "webrtc": signal_data,
                    "user": user
                }
            )

    def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event["message"]
        user = event["user"]

        # Send message to WebSocket
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({"message": message, 'user': user}))

    def webrtc_signal(self, event):
        signal_data = event["webrtc"]
        user = event["user"]

        # Send WebRTC signaling data to WebSocket
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            "webrtc": signal_data,
            "user": user
        }))

**VideoChat.js
**



    const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
    const localAudioRef = useRef(null);
    const remoteAudioRef = useRef(null);
    const peerConnectionRef = useRef(null);
    const [localStream, setLocalStream] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const initializeSocket = () => {
            const newSocket = new WebSocket(`ws://${window.location.host}/ws/chat/1/`);
            setSocket(newSocket);

            newSocket.onopen = () => {
                console.log('WebSocket connected');
            };

            newSocket.onmessage = async (event) => {
                const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
                console.log('Message received:', data);
                const messageType = data.webrtc?.type;

                if (messageType === 'offer') {
                    await handleOffer(data.webrtc);
                } else if (messageType === 'answer') {
                    await handleAnswer(data.webrtc);
                } else if (messageType === 'ice-candidate') {
                    await handleIceCandidate(data.webrtc.candidate);
                }
            };

            newSocket.onclose = () => {
                console.log('WebSocket disconnected');
            };

            return newSocket;
        };

        const getLocalStream = async () => {
            try {
                const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: false, audio: true });
                setLocalStream(stream);
                if (localAudioRef.current) {
                    localAudioRef.current.srcObject = stream;
                }
                setupPeerConnection(stream);
            } catch (err) {
                console.error('Error accessing media devices:', err);
                alert('Could not access microphone. Please check your device permissions and ensure no other applications are using the microphone.');
            }
        };

        const setupPeerConnection = (stream) => {
            const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({
                iceServers: [{ urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }]
            });


            peerConnectionRef.current = peerConnection;

            stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
                console.log('Adding track:', track, stream);
                peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream);
            });

            peerConnection.ontrack = (event) => {
                console.log('ontrack event triggered');
                console.log('Event:', event);
                console.log('Streams:', event.streams);

                if (event.streams && event.streams[0]) {
                    console.log('Remote Stream:', event.streams[0]);
                    if (remoteAudioRef.current) {
                        remoteAudioRef.current.srcObject = event.streams[0];
                    }
                } else {
                    console.error('No streams in event.');
                }
            };

            peerConnection.onicecandidate = (event) => {
                if (event.candidate) {
                    console.log('Sending ICE candidate:', event.candidate);
                    socket.send(JSON.stringify({
                        webrtc: {
                            type: 'ice-candidate',
                            candidate: event.candidate
                        }
                    }));
                } else {
                    console.log('ICE candidate gathering complete.');
                }
            };
        };

        const handleOffer = async (offer) => {
            const peerConnection = peerConnectionRef.current;
            await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer));
            const answer = await peerConnection.createAnswer();
            await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);

            socket.send(JSON.stringify({
                webrtc: {
                    type: 'answer',
                    sdp: peerConnection.localDescription
                }
            }));
        };

        const handleAnswer = async (answer) => {
            const peerConnection = peerConnectionRef.current;
            await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(answer));
        };

        const handleIceCandidate = async (candidate) => {
            const peerConnection = peerConnectionRef.current;
            if (peerConnection) {
                try {
                    await peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));
                    console.log('ICE candidate added:', candidate);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.error('Error adding ICE candidate:', e);
                }
            }
        };

        const socketInstance = initializeSocket();
        getLocalStream();

        return () => {
            if (localStream) {
                localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
            }
            if (socketInstance) {
                socketInstance.close();
            }
        };
    }, [roomName]);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Video Chat Room: {roomName}</h1>
            <audio ref={localAudioRef} autoPlay style={{ width: '45%' }} muted />
            <audio ref={remoteAudioRef} autoPlay style={{ width: '45%', marginLeft: '1rem' }} />
        </div>
    );


export default VideoChat;

The first connection is succesful and local is my microphone. Local works but when I open an incognito tab and join the same room instead of being added to remote it's being added to local at incognito mode.
This is what I get on console:
WebSocket connected
VideoChat.js:63 Adding track: MediaStreamTrack {kind: 'audio', id: '06f63e9a-d4b8-4ade-a6a7-47f3eff73fc0', label: 'Default - Microphone (KT USB Audio) (31b2:5075)', enabled: true, muted: false, …}
VideoChat.js:34 WebSocket disconnected

onicecandidate and ontrack don't run and only this
            stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
                console.log('Adding track:', track, stream);
                peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream);
            }); runs```

Instead of the incognito user being added as the ``remote`` it's just a new local. Also the websocket connection works.

Why is that and what could I do?

